# WiFi not working with kernel later than 4.14.8

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi, drivers, broadcom

I always upgraded the linux kernel of my machine to the latest stable version, but, with any version later than the 4.14.8 WiFI doesn't work anymore, how can i solve this?

Info about my wireless card:

```
description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 01
   serial: 74:29:af:e9:36:35
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=10.0.34.196 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:43 memory:f0c00000-f0c07fff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, they took the wl driver, which is what's used to run Broadcom wifi chips, out of the linux kernel starting at 4.14.8 . This only hit me now, when my Ubuntu box upgraded to kernel 4.15, and I suddenly didn't have wifi.

You need to install a DKMS version of the driver, which is broadcom-sta-dkms in debian based systems, and broadcom-wl-dkms in Arch. The source for the driver is [here on github](https://github.com/antoineco/broadcom-wl), if that's necessary.

Comment: The `wl` driver has never been a part of the actual Linux kernel, since it includes a proprietary Broadcom binary component with no source code available for it. Broadcom has not kept it up to date with Linux kernel development: the latest available version from that source is from year 2015. Since Broadcom seems to have abandoned it, other people have updated the part of the driver for which the source code *is* available, to adapt it to newer versions of the Linux kernel. This might technically be a violation of the driver license, but so far Broadcom seems to have had no problem with it.

Comment: every time when i trying to update dkms i am getting this ERROR: Missing 4.14.280-1-MANJARO kernel modules tree for module broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271. @A Gold Man any suggestion?